# Replace reST document with entire directory using Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

My primary documentation for a project is Sphinx. I also have a large amount of JavaDocs that I'd like to integrate. The basic setup is:

`sphinx_source/`

`javadocs_built/`

Before building the Sphinx documents, I can copy the JavaDocs into a directory under `sphinx_source`.

How can I reference this directory with non-reST files in it from within Sphinx and have them be brought along during the build process?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to reference the files using the `:download:` directive.

See: [here](http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html?highlight=download#role-download).

Note that you'll need to reference the files individually, so you may want to set up some kind of script to generate the references for you.